# Linuxtrack . Missing libraries

Tags: package-management, libraries

Following [installation instructions](https://github.com/uglyDwarf/linuxtrack/wiki/universal-Linuxtrack-package) for LinuxTrack (head tracker for TrackIR hardware), found some missing libraries.

```
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libcwiid.so.1 => not found
liblo.so.7 => not found
libQtCore.so.4 => not found
libQtGui.so.4 => not found
libQtNetwork.so.4 => not found
libQtOpenGL.so.4 => not found
libQtWebKit.so.4 => not found
libcwiid.so.1 => not found
libopencv_core.so.2.3 => not found
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3 => not found
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3 => not found
```

A search in https://packages.ubuntu.com/ retrieved packages that contained the files. I searched the exact filename and the results were packages that contained either the exact match, or similar files, example:

**Missing file: libQtWebKit.so.4**

**Found in package: libQtWebKit.so.4.10.2**

All required/found libs were exact matches, except:
libQtWebKit.so.4 ; libopencv_core.so.2.3 ; libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3

Then I extracted just the library files from the .deb with:

```
ar -vx <package name>
```

And finally copied the lot into /usr/lib

However, attempting to run Linuxtrack GUI with `ltr_gui` returns:

```
ltr_gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is probably due to the version mismatch of some of the libs.
I can't find the exact match file. What can I do? (noob here).
Thank you.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details. but details provided seem to imply you're trying to use something old; a Qt4 app? where Qt4 was replaced by Qt5 in 2012 and removed from Debian/Ubuntu late 2019, but release details are a necessary start.

Comment: Of course! Sorry.

Ubuntu 20.10; 
Linux 5.8.0-41-generic x86_64. The app I'm trying to use is the latest LinuxTrack from the developer's page. (link on top of text).

Comment: http://linuxtrack.eu/repositories/universal/linuxtrack-0.99.18-64.zip